# Wordpress stop multiple form submission

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am making a simple form with a submit button inside of it. In order to do this I used a shortcode which returns the form. I would like to prevent the user from submitting the form multiple times. However, the answers I have found tend to rely on disabling the button using javascript in some way. If I understand correctly this has two problems.

1. If the user stops the page, the button will be permanently disabled.
2. The client code can be changed manually by the user to send multiple requests even if the button is disabled.

I was wondering if there is some way to handle this on the server side in php?

The main problem I am having is that the shortcode needs to return something. It is possible to store a unique code using a nonce, the database or other methods to uniquely identify the submission. However, I can't find a way to cancel execution before the shortcode starts.

Also, when I was trying things I found that if I sleep the function so I can spam the submit button, only the final shortcode submission is returned. So I can't simply return a working copy of the form either.

It seems this would be a standard problem, so am I missing something?